# Adding new column to table as foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having difficult time trying to add a column to my sql table that will be a foreign key to another table. I'm getting the following error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''description_id' INT,
ADD FOREIGN KEY (description_id)
REFERENCES description(de' at line 2
```

From my query:

```
ALTER TABLE images
ADD COLUMN 'description_id' INT,
ADD FOREIGN KEY (description_id)
REFERENCES description(description_id)
```

Here is my table, where I am trying to add the column to:

```
CREATE TABLE `images` (
  `id` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `pattern` varchar(225) DEFAULT NULL,
  `color` varchar(225) DEFAULT NULL,
  `imageUrl` varchar(225) DEFAULT NULL,
  `imageSource` varchar(225) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=47 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Here is the table that is being connected:

```
CREATE TABLE `description` (
  `description_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `color` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pattern` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `body` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`description_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: try ` (back ticks) instead of ' (single quotes) after `ADD COLUMN 'description_id'`.

Comment: @Qeremy that was the fix. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't ALTER TABLE ADD, ADD. Try:

```
ALTER TABLE images
ADD COLUMN 'description_id' INT
REFERENCES description(description_id)
```